# Ruby beginner trying to call a method from another class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the below working. Not sure where I am failing. I receive the following error:

1) Error:

```
test_google(Google):
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Method:Class
    google.rb:15:in `setup'
```

I am new to ruby, so this is pretty 101. Can someone explain to me my errors and why so I can understand. Thanks!

```
require "test/unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "json"
require "time"
require_relative "methods"

class Google < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
    @search = Method.new()
  end 

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end 

  def test_google
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @search.search
  end 

end

class Method

  def search
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").clear
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").send_keys "this is a test"
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
  end 

end
```

I changed the class name:

```
require "test/unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "json"
require "time"


class Google < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
    @search = Suber.new()
  end 

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end 

  def test_google
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @search.search
  end 

end


class Suber


  def search
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").clear
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").send_keys "this is a test"
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
  end 


end
```

Now I am not exactly sure how to tackle setting @driver within my 'Suber' class. I assumed it would just work, but it throws:

NoMethodError: undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass
    google.rb:37:in`search'
    google.rb:25:in `test_google'

: /

Comment: I have added the answer for your second part.Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your edit do the below:

```
require "test/unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "json"
require "time"

module Suber


  def search
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").clear
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").send_keys "this is a test"
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
      @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
  end 


end

class Google < Test::Unit::TestCase

  include Suber

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
    #@search = Suber.new()
  end 

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end 

  def test_google
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    search
  end 

end
```

Comment: it will still be there. His `Method` class is not inheriting any other class, so `search` instance method doesn't have any knowledge about `@driver`

Answer (score 5):

Method is a built in class in Ruby (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html) You'll have to rename your class to something else.

Comment: Thank you! However, now I receive:
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass
    google.rb:35:in `search'
    google.rb:25:in `test_google'

So I feel like I am still not calling the class properly. Should the instance variables within my Mothod class just work when being called within Google? Or do I need to define something within the Method class? 'find_element' is a built in method for selenium webdriver which I call in Google.

Comment: @user2120790, and you're not setting `@driver` on the new class before using it in `find_element`.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a solution but if you have the time, the book Metaprogramming Ruby goes over classes in good detail.